# Why is this Javascript printing my comments in the rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, comments

I'm new to Javascript, as in just really getting started with it today. I'm testing some very basic code in the first chapter of a book and encountered a problem on the first example. I wrote the code in Notepad++, but even in that program my second line of commenting is black and not green. **Why does the line right after `</noscript>` render?**

[image: Code as rendered in Notepad++]

The output to my browser is rendered as: `Hello World! // Display a message dialog after the page has loaded.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "panel">
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    // Dynamically write a text string as the page loads.
    document.write("Hello World!");
    </script>
    <noscript>Javascript is Not Enabled!</noscript>
    // Display a message dialog after the page has loaded.
    <body onload = " window.alert('Document Loaded!');">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You also have two BODY tags in your HTML.

Comment: // Display a message dialog after the page has loaded. needs to be inside your script tag. You've got it outside

Comment: Essentially, anywhere you want to include a JS comment (`//`), place it inside your `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: I found downloadable code samples from the author's website. When I compared his to what he described in the book, I saw I was vastly off. I chalk it up to his books' poor presentation. What kind of language book never shows full code block examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you're writing your comment not in a JavaScript part but in an HTML one.

Comments in HTML are like this :

```
<noscript>Javascript is Not Enabled!</noscript> 
<!-- Display a message dialog after the page has loaded. -->
```

Note that you've put a `body` element inside the `body`, that's not good. You probably wanted this instead of the second body :

```
<script>
     window.onload = function(){
          alert('document loaded!');
     };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This book is poorly written and the author never shows you a fully assembled code block.

Answer (score 3):

`<!-- This is a comment in HTML -->`
`/* This is a comment in Javascript */`

Comment: Use of `/* */` is frowned upon because of the possibility of inadvertent closure by unintended `*/`.  Better to use `//`.

Comment: @DerekHenderson Hmm. Haven't heard that one before and not sure I really follow the reasoning. Perhaps I'm just missing something, though. Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I don't remember the various places I've seen this.  One of them may very well have been Douglas Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts.  The reasoning is that most developers work in environments where multiple developers might edit a file and problems can happen. Say someone inadvertently sticks a new comment block inside the original comment block -- well, now both comment blocks are closed!  This is avoided entirely is all commented lines start with `//` and one is less likely to accidentally add a comment block inside another comment block.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the line you tried to comment out is rendered is because you have attempted to comment out the text with JavaScript comments.

The browser rendering html sees the two slashes (`//`) as part of the text, not as markup designating a comment.

The correct way to comment out something in html is with `<!--` and `-->`.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  This answer is technically correct and addresses the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment are not between script tag. You can move it into an script tag or use the HTML comment just like @22kar said.
Also you need to put the parameter "onload" in the first body tag and remove the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try use php tag on every your comment. That won't show your comments in the html source.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35776085)